# Flutter Casting a Map<String, dynamic> to Future<Map<String, dynamic>> forcefully returns Error

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a function that contains some Future returns as show below.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> myFunction() {
  if(some_condition){
    returnFromThisFunc = {
        'status': false,
        'message':'Some message',
        'data': {}
    } as Future<Map<String, dynamic>>;    // Error mentioning this line at 'as'
  } else {
    // Returning "Future<Map<String, dynamic>> returnFromThisFunc" return from some API and etc functions that are working fine.
  }
  return returnFromThisFunc;
}
```

Now the problem is that if my `some_condition` is false then it is working fine and function is returning the data but when `some_condition` is true then it is giving me this error `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast`

How to fix this and return `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>` in any way...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your function return type is `Future` you should use await in it, but when you don't have any async method in it, you should use `Future.value` for returning value. try this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> myFunction() {
  if(some_condition){
    returnFromThisFunc = {
        'status': false,
        'message':'Some message',
        'data': {}
    }
  } else {
    // Returning "Future<Map<String, dynamic>> returnFromThisFunc" return from some API and etc functions that are working fine.
  }
  return Future.value(returnFromThisFunc) ;/// <--- add this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.value` on return.

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> myFunction() {
  Map<String, dynamic> returnFromThisFunc;
  if (1 < 2) {
    returnFromThisFunc = {
      'status': false,
      'message': 'Some message',
      'data': {}
    }; 
  } else {
    returnFromThisFunc = {};
  }
  return Future.value(returnFromThisFunc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> myFunction() {
  if(some_condition){
    returnFromThisFunc = {
        'status': false,
        'message':'Some message',
        'data': {}
    }
  } else {
    // Returning "Future<Map<String, dynamic>> returnFromThisFunc" return from some API and etc functions that are working fine.
  }
  return Future.value(returnFromThisFunc); // <= add this
}
```

Feel free to comment me if you have any questions.